# Most simple way from data to chart

Tags: python, charts

I have data like this:

```
x;file-size;duration;mem-size
0;0;0.04456615448;478359552
1;10040000;0.39223408699;562151424
2;20080000;0.725513935089;585662464
3;30120000;1.0728430748;615784448
4;40160000;1.40820503235;692932608
5;50200000;2.27191090584;702971904
6;60240000;2.91427922249;713015296
7;70280000;3.06625103951;857272320
8;80320000;3.59500288963;867311616
9;90360000;4.14507699013;877350912
10;100400000;4.07794499397;887390208
11;110440000;4.49854111671;897429504
12;120480000;6.11765384674;907472896
13;130520000;5.25889492035;917512192
14;140560000;8.49787211418;1195986944
15;150600000;7.62461209297;1206026240
16;160640000;11.1224441528;1216065536
17;170680000;10.2002708912;1226104832
18;180720000;10.042427063;1236148224
19;190760000;10.516712904;1246187520
20;200800000;11.7282280922;1256226816
21;210840000;12.0539629459;1266266112
22;220880000;14.2956900597;1276305408
23;230920000;10.0558278561;1286344704
24;240960000;16.1226639748;1296388096
25;251000000;14.6481440067;1306427392
26;261040000;13.0455079079;1316466688
```

The first column should be the x axis and the other values should be on the y axis and somehow distinguishable.

It should roughly look like this:

[image: chart]

The x value should be the year.

The headings "file-size", "duration", "mem-size" should be taken from the first line of the csv file.

Required features:

- open source
- runs on Ubuntu
- auto-scaling: the tool should check all input values and scale the chart
- the lines should have the matching heading as annotation
- If new columns get added it should simply draw an additional line.
- If programming is needed (I hope it is not), then it should be python

Optional features:

- callable via command-line

Comment: Import to OpenOffice spreadsheet or excel as a delimited file, then use the built in chart making tools.  Maybe make it super easy by first doing a search/replace to replace the semicolon with comma, making it a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

I think `gnuplot` can do that. There is a [web interface](http://gnuplot.respawned.com/) for playing with some sample data.

My personal preference would be to call *R* from the command line using the [Rio script](https://github.com/jeroenjanssens/data-science-at-the-command-line/blob/master/tools/Rio) .

Answer (score 0):

I used matplotlib and Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Source https://github.com/guettli/misc/blob/master/bench-bytea-inserts-postrgres.py
# Chart: https://github.com/guettli/misc/blob/master/bench-bytea-inserts-postrgres.png

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_License
#     <Copyright Information>
#    Usage of the works is permitted provided that this instrument is retained with the works, 
#    so that any entity that uses the works is notified of this instrument.
#    DISCLAIMER: THE WORKS ARE WITHOUT WARRANTY.

import os
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

import psycopg2

db = psycopg2.connect(dbname=os.environ['USER'])
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
drop table if exists bytea_test;
create table bytea_test (
    data bytea
    )
;
''')
random_stream = open('/dev/urandom', 'rb')
rows=[]
for i in range(0, 1*10**8, 10000000):
    data = psycopg2.Binary(random_stream.read(i))
    start_time = time.time()
    cursor.execute('''insert into bytea_test values (%s)''', (data,))
    duration_random = time.time()-start_time

    data = 'x'*i
    start_time = time.time()
    cursor.execute('''insert into bytea_test values (%s)''', (data,))
    duration_ascii = time.time()-start_time
    kilo_bytes = i / 1000
    row = (kilo_bytes, duration_ascii, duration_random)
    print('{},'.format(row))
    rows.append(row)
m = numpy.array(rows).transpose()
plt.plot(m[0], m[1], label='ascii')
plt.plot(m[0], m[2], label='random')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('kilo bytes insert into bytea column')
plt.ylabel('duriation (seconds)')
plt.show()
```